# Can I test MBA motherboard using only charger and external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, apple-hardware-test, motherboard

Can I test a Macbook Air (2011-2015) motherboard using only the charger and external monitor?

Comment: Test it for what exactly?

Comment: Can it run the installer (mean it work normally)

Comment: I don’t see why not.   You have to try.